# ajax multi file upload stuck on request in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

when I upload multiple file in a laravel project using ajax request the request always shows pending in network panel but when I upload or choose only one file then its working. I can't find what's wrong. I also used jquery validation. Please help-

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple id="product-image" name="file[]">
```

JS:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
 var serializeData = new FormData($(form).get(0));
 serializeData.append('description',$('#summernote-description').code());
 $.ajax({
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  method: $(form).attr('method'),
  data: serializeData,
  url: $(form).attr('action'),
  success:function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
   }
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the form HTML?

Comment: form is so big but as a short  `<form id="addProductForm" method="post"
                      action="{{route('admin::product.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple id="product-image" name="file[]">
</form>`

Comment: Use Chrome's inspector, in the network tab you can see what's happening with the request and where it's being blocked